# How to get local port and IP in Network Kernel Extension(Socket filter) in kernel context of MacOS

Tags: macos, kernel-extension, networkextension

I am looking to collect Port and IP of the connecting socket to the socket filter in Network Kernel Extention (NKE).

I have tried to collect it in `sf_bind, sf_connect_in, sf_connect_out` call back functions of `struct sflt_filter`.

In `sf_bind(void *cookie,socket_t so,const struct sockaddr *to)` callback. it specified for `to` param "The local address of the socket will be bound to" So I have used code:

```
printf("Local port:<%u> and IP<%04X>", 
        ntohs(((struct sockaddr_in *)to)->sin_port), 
        ntohs(((struct sockaddr_in*)to)->sin_addr.s_addr));
```

Sometimes both IP and Port is empty and sometimes one of the both is appearing.

And in same and other callbacks I have tried with code:

```
unsigned char szAddrStr[256];
struct sockaddr_in addrLcl;
sock_getsockname(so, (struct sockaddr *)&addrLcl, sizeof(addrLcl));
inet_ntop(AF_INET, &addrLcl.sin_addr, (char *)szAddrStr, sizeof(szAddrStr));
printf("IP String <%s> Port Hex:<%X>", szAddrStr, ntohs(addrLcl.sin_port));
```

But this code always gives IP and Port empty.

Has anyone had any idea? or another way to get it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

About your first code fragment: It's hard to say what is exactly wrong without full callback code sample, but you definetely should check sa_family field of "to" before trying to print sin_port and sin_addr as port and ip.

I think the values you are looking for are AF_INET and AF_INET6.

About your second code fragment: you should again check sa_family;

Also, calling sock_getsockname on "so" in bind callback could be wrong, because that "callbacks" are called before relevant operations and you will not have filled sockaddr for "so".

There is [tcplognke](https://github.com/gdbinit/tcplognke) sample (it was once on apple developers resources, but they are not good at care about them), you should check it out for examples.

And there is an information about Apple plans to make NKE technology [deprecated soon](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/79590), so be careful using it :)